# using one fragment, Listener, method multiple times in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment with a seekbar in its layout. I successfully add an interface in the fragment and implemented this interface in main activity so I can read the value of seekbar once it's moved. I would like to have the 2nd instance of this fragment in my activity and display its seekbar progress (value) separately, but I cannot. moving any of those seekbars (from two different fragment) change the the value of the same textview in the main activity? Here is the code. Your Help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OneIntSlideFragment.MyIntSlideListener {

TextView myTxt1, myTxt2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myTxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    myTxt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2id);

    OneIntSlideFragment SlideFragment1 = (OneIntSlideFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentID1);
    OneIntSlideFragment SlideFragment2 = (OneIntSlideFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentID2);

}
    // this gets called by OneIntSlideFragment when Seekbar is changed
@Override
public void myIntSlideMethod(int slideValue) {
   int myNum = slideValue;
   if(myTxt1 != null){
       myTxt1.setText(String.valueOf(myNum));
   }
}
}
```

and the code for fragment is:

```
public class OneIntSlideFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable

private int mySeekBarValue;
TextView intSlideTitle, intSlideMinTxt, intSlideMaxTxt;
TextView intSlideNumTV;

MyIntSlideListener mListener;

public interface MyIntSlideListener{
    public void myIntSlideMethod (int slideValue);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof MyIntSlideListener)
        mListener = (MyIntSlideListener)context;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_int_slide_fragment, container, false);

    SeekBar mySeekBar;
    intSlideNumTV = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.intSlideNumID);
    mySeekBar = (SeekBar) myView.findViewById(R.id.intSeekBarID);

    mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mySeekBarValue = progress;
            intSlideNumTV.setText(":  " + progress);

            mListener.myIntSlideMethod(mySeekBarValue);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
}
```

Comment: Add an argument to your functional interface method `myIntSlideMethod()` like an `int` or `enum` or something that you can parse as unique, then just use a `switch` or `if else` statement in you `Activity` implementation of that method to do something based on each value.

Comment: Hi Mark,  I think I can't use setArguments() when I embed the fragment within XML, can I ?

Comment: A better solution is to use `FrameLayout`s in your XML and use the `FragmentManager` to add then to the different containers - that way you can create new instances of your Fragment and set the arguments you want to include in the bundle, obviously changing between the 2 instances.

Comment: it worked but caused another problem. I have another textview in my fragment (not included in the above code) where I set its text through main activity.

        public void myMethod (String title){
        intSlideTitle.setText(title);
    }

and in the main activity I have 

SlideFragment1.myMethod("Slide A");

now the app crashes at this point.

Comment: Then use Fragment manager to find the Fragment `findFragmentById` and pass the container (Frame layout) id - you now have a reference to your Fragment where you can call the method to set the text.

Comment: I think the problem is intSlideTitle is null when SlideFragment1.myMethod("Slide A");  is executed in main Activity.   any idea how to fix it?  I like your original solution, but do not know how to overcome the new issue.

Comment: You have Direct references to Fragments that don't exist anymore - you no longer place Fragments directly into the XML.